# Laravel share is too high on server

Tags: laravel, server, composer-php, laravel-artisan

Our service uses Apache and PHP 7.1 for Nginx

When Laravel turns around on the server, it increases the share of the server every moment, making it difficult to use.

1. artisan config:cache
2. artisan route:cache
3. artisan optimize
4. composer dumpautoload

We performed the above process and optimized it as much as possible.

However, there is still a problem of increasing the market share which is difficult to prove from the server yet.

Maybe if I serve Laravel, I care if it will be more than to do other things.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you're trying to say. Are you having performance issues?

Comment: are you sure you're on `prod` environment?